# change mat-form-field to stuck on floating mode

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How to make the `mat-form-field` stuck on his floating mode.

| Actual | Needed |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following class `mat-form-field-should-float` make the trick.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Téléphone</mat-label>
  <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input
    [preferredCountries]="['ch', 'de', 'fr', 'it']"
    [enableSearch]="true"
    name="phone"
    formControlName="phone"
  ></ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```